# Печать и индикатор прогрузки

Tags: print, ajax, печать

Здравствуйте, у меня есть два вопроса, если поможете, буду очень благодарен.

1) Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатие на кнопку началась печать документа, НО:

а) Данные должны подставить в определенную форму

б) Не должно всплывать окно выбора принтера и т.д.

Простой пример использования: составлен заказ, мы кликнули печать и вылезла фактура на данный заказ. То есть обычный window.print не делает всего этого.

2) Как сделать индикатор загрузки в тот момент пока выполняется ajax запрос? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатие на кнопку началась печать документа

Использовать плагин [printPage](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-printPage-plugin)

---

> Не должно всплывать окно выбора принтера и т.д.

Средствами JS - никак, если не ошибаюсь.

---

> Как сделать индикатор загрузки в тот момент пока выполняется ajax запрос

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
        // Show loader
    });

    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
        // Hide loader
    });

    $( document ).ajaxError(function() {
        // Hide loader
    });
});
```

Comment: А как привязать данную функцию к определенному ajax запросу а не ко всем? Если обращаться к документу, то это будет привязано ко всем запросам. Спасибо

Comment: Код ajax запроса продемонстрируйте.

Comment: $('.plus').click(function(){
                id_wait_confirm=$(this).val();
                
        $.post(
              "/work.php",
      {
          id_wait_confirm: id_wait_confirm
      },
      onAjaxSuccess
              );
      function onAjaxSuccess(data)
      {
          alert (data);
      }
    
    });